# Sending image or message through push notification

Tags: iphone, xcode

I developing a chat app in which user can send and receive messages through push notification.I am using php to send messages to server.When i send messages to another mobile in case of app closed that push notification will be displayed in home screen of the mobile as "You received message from john ".So the user click the push notification and open the app to see the message.When user not click push notification means my app not receiving any message.

Comment: How do i get message when user not click push notification message?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will only get the push message payload when the user actions the notification or the notification is received while your app is in the foreground.

This is why you should not be using push deliver content to your app. It is only intended to let the user know that there is new content. Your app should be responsible for pulling any new content from your backend server as soon as it is in a position to do so.

Comment: Taking the answer by nduplessis, you should use your own server or use any ready server like Urban Airship. urbanairship.com/